# my_thread_global_end threads didn't exit, error?

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, macos

I am using MySQL c++ connector (1.0.5) , recently I moved get_driver_instance() and connect() methods to secondary thread then I am getting below error.

> Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit

After googling I found that mysql thread isn't exiting. Is there a method in c++ wrapper to do cleanup?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After googling I came to know that [mysql_thread_end](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-thread-end.html)() will solve the problem. Any way I was linking against libmysqlclient.a so included mysql.h file and called mysql_thread_end before exiting secondary thread, now the problem is solved.

Comment: Wow! Got same error. But why does it raises? Is there any "true" or "correct" ways to avoid that error?

Comment: could not find this function in my library. I am use cppconn. where is this function? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you use *MySQL Connector/C++* with threads, you have to encapsulate your mysql-part within `sql::Driver::threadInit()` and `sql::Driver::threadEnd()`.

I have found another similar question [here](/questions/16165322/threads-that-have-mysql-connector-code-in-c-dont-end).

Before you use any other function of the connector inside a thread, you can write something like

```
sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance(); // should be synchronized
driver->threadInit();
```

And before the thread stops but after all other mysql-stuff, you can write somethink like

```
driver->threadEnd();
```

---

It also seems that `get_driver_instance()` is not thread safe. I get segmentation faults sometimes if I do not synchronize it. In my case I had a segmentation fault while initialization in circa one of two tests. Since I'm synchronizing the call to `get_driver_instance()`, I did not have a segmentation fault right now.

Answer (score 1):

When using C++/connector, do the equivalent:

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
  :
  :

driver->threadEnd();  // must be done or sql thread leaks on app exit with: 
                      // Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
```

Answer (score -1):

Additional info:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?37,565890,565890 and links therein.